# undefined method `merge' for :name:Symbol

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use a select box in my form. when I try it this way

```
<%= s_form.select :experience_category_id, ExperienceCategory.all, :name,:id%>
```

it gives me the error

> undefined method merge for :name:Symbol.

may be because I have to use the signature `s_form.collection_select`.but it doesnt allow me multiple selection.

when I try it this way

```
<%= s_form.select(:experience_category_id, ExperienceCategory.all {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] },
                                             { :prompt => "Please select"},
                                             { :multiple => true, :size => ExperienceCategory.all.count } )%>
```

**Supplier_controller**

```
def new
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_supplier
    @user.supplier.build_natural_address
  end
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.role = "supplier"

      if @user.save
        UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
        flash[:notice] = "Please check your email to activate your account"
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render :new
      end

  end
```

. .  .

```
def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, supplier_attributes: [:id, :company_name, :insurance_document, :profile_image, :national,:experience_category_id, natural_address_attributes: [:addressable_id, :addressable_scope, :addressable_type, :address_line_1, :address_line_2, :address_line_3, :town, :county, :postcode]])
    end
```

The Supplier is created I cant see any problem in the server but with out an `:experience_catagory_id`.
It doesnt throw an error but the `:experience_category_id` stays `nil`.what can be the problem? and  How can I solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: when I use `.map` or `.collect` it returns me an Enum and when I use `.pluck` it returns me an array of all the catagories which all of them are good but still `p` is `nil`

Comment: What's on the rails server logs, and in your controller?

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this link](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select#340-Refactoring-excessive-code-for-selects) is good sample reference for your problem

for your problem if you want to choose one choice

```
<%= s_form.collection_select :experience_category_id, ExperienceCategory.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select' %>
```

for multiple choice

```
<%= s_form.collection_select :experience_category_ids, ExperienceCategory.all, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true'} %>
```

in your controller please note especially in your strong_parameters it should be an array

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(
    :your_other_fields,
    :experience_category_ids => []
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= f.select(:experience_category_id, ExperienceCategory.find(:all).collect {|u| [u.name, u.id]}, :prompt => 'Select') %>
```

Comment: tags on this post are unclear but...If this is rails 3 then `ExperienceCategory.find(:all)` is identical to `ExperienceCategory.all` (and thus identical to the OP current proposal).  If this is rails 4 then `ExperienceCategory.find(:all)` will fail as `#find` now coerces `to_i` for integer based primary keys. In either case the `select` will not allow multiple without you explicitly adding that option

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the correct format as per rails html helps

use this

```
<%= f.select(:product_category_id, product.find(:all).collect {|u| [u.name, u.id]}, :prompt => 'Select') %>
```

or

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'None'})
```

as in documentation
[Rails helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)